# Friendly URLs in Phoenix 1.3 undefined error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, friendly-url

I'm trying to implement friendly URLs in my app based on the following guide https://elixircasts.io/seo-friendly-urls-with-phoenix.
The slug is being created in the db from the post title ok, but I cannot get the post to show when looking up by the slug and get the following error:

`function Driverless.Articles.get_by!/2 is undefined or private`

**post_controller.ex**

```
...
  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    post = Articles.get_by!(Post, slug: id)
    render(conn, "show.html", post: post)
  end
...
```

**post.ex**

```
...
  def changeset(%Post{} = post, attrs) do
    attrs = Map.merge(attrs, slug_map(attrs))
    post
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :snippet, :body, :slug])
    |> validate_required([:title, :snippet, :body])
  end

  defp slug_map(%{"title" => title}) do
    slug = String.downcase(title) |> String.replace(" ", "-")
    %{"slug" => slug}
  end
  defp slug_map(_attrs) do
    %{}
  end
...
```

I'm sure there's a small error somewhere, but just can't spot it.

Comment: Did you mean to do `Repo.get_by!`?

Comment: Tried that: `function Repo.get_by!/2 is undefined (module Repo is not available)`.

v1.3 generates  `Articles.get_by!` from the scaffold.

Comment: Ah, I haven't used Phoenix 1.3 recently and they've been moving stuff around since RC0. Is there a `get_by!/2` function in `Driverless.Articles`?

Comment: The console produces:

    `driverless Driverless.Articles.get_by!/2

    [Post, [slug: "3"]]`

Comment: No, still getting the error.

Comment: Do you mean `Driverless.Repo.get_by!(Post, slug: id)` or `Driverless.Articles.Repo.get_by!(Post, slug:id)`? What module is `Repo` under specifically? That module is what should prepend `Repo` for the `get_by!`

Comment: Can you show us the generated Driverless.Articles module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solved this:

Unlike the original example in Elixir casts, we leave the post controller as is:

```
  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    post = Articles.get_post!(id)
    render(conn, "show.html", post: post)
  end
```

I just made the change to:

**articles.ex**

From:

```
def get_post!(id), do: Repo.get!(Post, id)
```

To

```
def get_post!(id), do: Repo.get_by!(Post, slug: id)
```